# fcm firebase HTC cannot get message

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I discovered that my HTC ONE X cannot get message sending by fcm(google firebase). So, are there specifications for android devices using fcm? And, how to support the devices like HTC ONE X?

Comment: Are you sending push notification from Firebase console or using an app server with Firebase Cloud Messaging? If you're using FCM, could you please provide the notification or data payload you've used to send messages to your device?

Comment: @looptheloop88 It has no problems when using samsung device or nexus 5. So, the problem is related to HTC ONE X device, but I don't know why.

Comment: I understand how you feel. Could you please check if the device can generate a registration token?

Comment: @looptheloop88 I tested again. Sometimes, it got the message. So, it may be related to network actually.

Comment: Maybe. In the best-case scenario, if the device is connected to FCM, the screen is on and there are no throttling restrictions, the message is delivered right away. You can also check if there's an ongoing service disruption in the Firebase Status Dashboard.

Comment: @looptheloop88 Thanks.